# erroneous net-snmp error handling

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp

Is it possible to catch errors (for instance due to timeout) with net-snmp in python?

I am using this code:

```
import netsnmp
import pprint

session = netsnmp.Session(Version = 2, DestHost='192.168.0.1', 
          Community='public', Timeout=10000, Retries=1, UseNumeric=1)
oid_obj = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1'))
value_obj = session.walk(oid_obj)

# print the result and the error codes:
pprint.pprint(value_obj)
print("Error status: ", session.ErrorStr, session.ErrorNum, session.ErrorInd)
```

Due to short timeout I get incomplete results - which is fine (note that timeout is in *microseconds*). What is not fine is that I get no error indication:

```
('1001', '1002', '1003')
('Error status: ', '', 0, 0)
```

Am I looking in the wrong place?

This is what I am using: (installed as Debian package)

```
Package: libsnmp-python                  
Version: 5.4.3~dfsg-2
Homepage: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/
```

I would appreciate some help, or even advice on which SNMP library to take (if Net-SNMP doesn't handle errors properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to 5.4.4 there was a bug in Net-SNMP python bindings (didn't return error codes) - upgrade solved the issue. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Still m getting empty string in ErrorStr in

Working on OEL linux:
Installed the following version :

`net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64`

`net-snmp-python-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64`

`net-snmp-utils-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64`

`net-snmp-libs-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64`

Not able to get the ErrorStr for Timeout.

Could some help.

thanks sapamja

Comment: Sorry, can't help you - but you should post your question as a new one, not as answer. I saw your question just because I was notified of it and I doubt anyone else will see it. Click "Ask question" (top right) and continue from there. Good luck!

Comment: thank you i asked in separate question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688292/python-net-snmp-binding-return-empty-errorstr

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.7.3 (built from Source RPM  : net-snmp-5.7.3-4.5.src.rpm) the ErrorNum is always zero, but ErrorStr will have a value.